# C# + AD LDS - Help interpreting error message

Tags: c#, active-directory, adlds

I've written some code to manage membership of an AD LDS container using C#. In our testing, an error is thrown when attempting to commit our changes to the `DirectoryEntry` if certain people are added. The code works fine if these specific users aren't included in the membership.

The detailed exception that is generated is:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147016657
>   Message=A constraint violation occurred.
>
> Source=System.DirectoryServices
>   ErrorCode=-2147016657
>   ExtendedError=8373
>   ExtendedErrorMessage=000020B5: AtrErr: DSID-03152804, #1:
>   0: 000020B5: DSID-03152804, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 1f (member)
>
> StackTrace:
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()
>   at HCI.DirectoryServices.AdLds.Role.Save() in c:\Projects\ET\Shared\HCI.DirectoryServices\AdLds\Role.cs:line 186
>   at HCI.Test.ADManager.PasswordModifier.Main() in c:\Projects\ET\ADManager\HCI.Test.ADManager\Program.cs:line 303
>   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

From what I have read online, this message indicates there is a problem with the member attribute of the group, but I have no idea what it could be. As I stated, the same code works perfectly when these specific users are excluded. I haven't been able to find any commonality with the problem users either.

For a final kicker, if I manually add these users to the container using ADSI Edit, I can then do anything I want to with them with my code: remove, add back, add to a different container, etc.

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: I assume by container you mean a group? Do the DNs of these users have any characters that need to be escaped? For example a comma?

Comment: No, nothing unusual at all.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can help you?